# Monero fork that does not support pooling?

Tags: monero-forks, altcoin

I saw a few days ago while getting my miner figured out someone mention on Reddit plans for a Monero fork that only allows solo mining to prevent 51% attacks from pools. I'm thinking it might be profitable to mine with a high end cpu. Does anyone know what the name of that coin should be when forked?

Answer (score 2):

It might be Wownero ?

wowario, one of the Wownero coders, was recently asking on IRC about a proposed system to sign a coinbase with the output secret key, which is a way to allow a miner to steal a pool's coinbase, and therefore disincentivize pool mining (there are ways around that, mostly for the pool to require a deposit, but that makes pool mining less attractive from a miner's point of view).

Comment: It also doesn't protect against botnets (which are the bigger concern wrt chain security), as these can just use a private pool and thus have no need to protect the coinbase from theft.

Comment: I think it might be a different fork. From reading the throw away Reddit post, awhile back, it sounded like he set it up so you can't distribute the load across multiple cpus, in a pool. If it does exist it's probably poorly publicized, and might not be worth using. Way too many altcoins.